# How to modify a uri string?

Tags: javascript

I need to retrieve a uri string from the database and open it in a new page. But it's surrounded by inverted commas at the beginning and at the end. How can I drop those?

for the one at the begin of the string, I tried with a `split` method as below:

```js
abilitaDownload(file) {
  const split1 = file.split(' " ')
  console.log("FILE" + split1)
  window.open(split1, "_blank_");
};
```

But, I still have the problem of the one at the end of the string. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yor're sending an array to `window.open`. For this you should use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove the extra quotes added.

Comment: If `file` has space-quote-space at both the beginning and end, splitting like this gives you an array with _three_ elements, so you just have to pick the middle one …

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.slice(0, -1)` to remove the last char of a string. and `slice(1)` to remove the first

```js
var string = '"aaaaav"'
string = string.slice(1).slice(0, -1);
console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to remove the first and last chars of a string, this can be done by:

```
const removedCommas = file.substring(1, file.length - 1)
```

Or you can replace all occurrences in a string by: (will remove all " chars in string)

```
const removedCommas = file.str.replace(/"/g, '')
```